# Hilbert Theory: validity in fields other than complex

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I was reading Rudin's book on elementary Hilbert space theory. Right off the bat he restricts value of an inner product to being a complex number. I just want some confirmation as to if all the theorems (such as Parseval's identity) holds if we were to restricts value of an inner product to being a real number, or any other field for that matter, (for example, finite field).

Comment: For one thing, the spectral theorem for bounded normal operators fails ...

Comment: To define a norm on a $K$-vector space you need an absolute value $|.|$ on $K$ so $K$ can't be a finite field. That the norm comes from an inner product implies there is a field automorphism $K\to K,z\to z^*$ such that $|z|^2=zz^*$, which means $K,|.|$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If the vector space is of finite dimension, the case $K=$ an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is interesting. In other fields you can consider normed vector spaces. In finite fields you can consider vector spaces with a bilinear and quadratic form.

Comment: Fourier analysis + finite field suggests you are thinking to the number theoretic transform, which is about diagonalizing circulant/convolution matrices over finite fields and any field.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the theorems are true for real scalars also. A  notable exception is the following: if $T$ is a bounded operator on a complex Hilbert space such that $ \langle Tx, x \rangle =0$ for all $x$ then $T$ is the zero operator. This is false for real scalars: just consider rotation by $90$ degrees in the plane. As pointed out in the comments there are other exceptions too when you go deeper into the theory. There are books on FA that do not assume that the scalar field is $\mathbb C$.